# CakePHP Logs Me Out Prematurely

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, fancybox

I have a CakePHP app that seems to be terminating my session on one specific action. I have a page which, when a link is clicked, launches a [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) overlay of the iframe type. In that overlay, the user fills out and submits a form. The form is submitted properly, does its work (including sending an email), loads the success view and lets me close the overlay, but as soon as I try to get to any other page, I'm sent to the login screen to reauthenticate.

The value of my `Security.level` config setting is `medium` and my `Session.timeout` is `120`, so that shouldn't be the problem. Anyone have any idea what could be creating this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this wasn't fun to track down, but it was me being an idiot. Buried in the code was some early-stage code to refresh user data in the authenticated session that wasn't doing what it should have been doing. It was attempting to update the entire `Auth.User` object directly (e.g. `$this->Session->write( 'Auth', $user )`) instead of calling the `login` method.

Once I changed the `Session::write()` code to `$this->Auth->login( $user )`, everything lined up nicely. A nice bit of reference material on this subject at http://milesj.me/blog/read/31/Refreshing-The-Auths-Session.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible that your ajax calls and redirects are not going to the same place, eg www.site.com and site.com? I have had that before and also kept getting logged out.

Comment: That _shouldn't_ be the case, but I'll definitely verify. I don't think there's any ajax actually happening (since the overlay is an iframe, I think it's direct request/response), but if this is a possible cause, I'll check it out. Thanks.